How to parse the content in a file to multiple protobuf message
For example, I have the following txt file, and I want to use python to parse them to two protobuf message lists. list1 contains an object of "description" and list2 contains two objects of "msg". What would be the best way to do it? I looked into the text_format.py defined by google protobuf, and there is a method called "parse" to parse the text to a message, but it seems it only generates one protobuf message each time, which means I would need to scan the txt file and feed the lines into the parse function. This seems a little cumbersome to me. Wonder whether there are better way to parse the file. Thanks!
 description {
              type: text
             }
 msg {
       text {
             message: "hello"
             caller: friend1
             }
       timestamp {
                  time:12345
                 }
      }
  msg {
        text {
              message: "how are you"
              caller: friend2
             }
         timestamp {
                    time:67890
                   }
       }


I'm familiar with protobuf but less so with the text format. Do you have the schema(s) that match(es) your file? I don't think it's valid: type: text and caller: friend1 appear incorrect since the values aren't evidently strings.

I reverse-engineered a schema for your message (with caveats for type and caller above). I learned that your text file is actually a single Protobuf Message, let's call it Foo which contains a Message called description and repeated Message called msg etc. So, you can text_format.Parse it in a single step.

@DazWilkin Thanks for replying. You are right, and text_format.Parse can do that with that file. I guess my question is what if there is another Protobuf Message right below what I have above (e.g., there is another description followed by 5 msg after the current message). Then how can I parse it?

When using binary-encoded protobuf messages, a practice is to prefix messages with a (varint) representing the upcoming message's length. This framing overcomes the fact that each message is variable length and thus difficult to parse without knowing its length. Using the text format and assuming no message-length framing, you're going to have to delimit messages by description {

My curiosity is piqued though: are you willing to share the system that is generating these text-formatted protobuf messages?

@DazWilkin Thanks for the suggestion. For the system, I actually derive the message from a very complicated protobuf definition, and I may not share it here.
